# Why does jQuery cookie not actually set a cookie?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-cookie

I am developing an application using jQuery that uses cookies. Right now, it is located at `application.html` on my PC desktop.

However, I cannot store and retrieve a cookie. I had included `jquery-1.7.1.min.js`, `json2.js`, and `jquery.cookie.js` in my HTML file in that order.

Here is how I am storing a cookie to last for 7 days:

```
$.cookie("people", JSON.stringify(people_obj_array), {expires: 7});
```

The global array `people_obj_array` looks like

```
[
        {
            "name": "Adam",
            "age": 1,
        },
        {
            "name": "Bob",
            "age": 2,
        },
        {
            "name": "Cathy",
            "age": 3,
        },
    ]
```

When I test JSON encryption with `alert(JSON.stringify(people_obj_array))`, it looks fine:

[image: JSON test]

However, when I retrieve this cookie via:

```
alert($.cookie("people"));
```

before even refreshing the page, an alert pops up that reads "null." Shouldn't the text be the alert JSON string? Am I using the JQuery cookies library correctly?

---

Just to clarify, here is how I am testing:

```
$.cookie("people", JSON.stringify(people_obj_array), {expires: 7}); // store
alert($.cookie("people")); // attempt to retrieve
```

I have Firebug, and I am willing to do some Console tests.

Comment: I think the issue is that the cookie mechanism is not defined for files on the local disk. Have you tried setting up a local web server and serving your file as `http://localhost/application.html`?

Comment: Thanks! I ended up just using local storage. It's much more straightforward and works both locally and on a web server. The downside is, of course, older browsers don't support it, which is fine for me. http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/11/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's probably the fact the file is on your desktop that's causing the problem. Browsers normally behave by serving up cookies based on the domain they were received from and their path.

You may not be able to read the cookie immediately after setting it: Writing a cookie involves  setting headers in a HTTP request and, likewise, reading them involves reading headers in a HTTP response.

Try hosting your page on a web-server and see if that works for you.

Comment: Thanks, I hosted the site on a public web server, and the cookies worked. This page has more details: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=535

Comment: @DavidFaux looks like you are using Chromium, so I can assume you are also using linux... well if you would like to setup a local webserver for testing you can `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^` then `sudo adduser <username> www-data`, then the following two commands. `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www` and `sudo chmod -R g+rw /var/www` should just about do it! then all your web dev goes in `/var/www` and you test by navigating to http://localhost/

Answer (score 2):

If you are having troubles with the cookies plugin why not just make up your own cookie functions? Read, Write and (optional) delete.

```
var createCookie = function(name, value, days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var expires = '; expires=' + date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = '';
        document.cookie = name + '=' + value + expires + '; path=/';
};
var readCookie = function(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + '=';
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
    }
    return null;
};
var eraseCookie = function(name) {
    createCookie(name, '', -1);
};
```

I cannot comment on the specific plugin as I have never used it.. however these functions all work and have been tested.

So for your example:

```
createCookie("people", JSON.stringify(people_obj_array), 7); // store
alert(readCookie("people")); // retrieve
eraseCookie("people"); // remove
alert(readCookie("people")); // oo look i'm no longer here.
```

Comment: Sure this works for web pages on the local disk? AFAIK some browser don't handle local cookies at all.

Comment: I have not tested that case.. however if cookies are not available locally, assuming the OP is using a modern browser *local storage* should work out..

Comment: Thanks! Local storage is working brilliantly. It's so simple too. http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/11/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/

Answer (score 1):

From my research `jquery.cookie.js` is fairly old, and doesn't *seem* to be maintained any longer. You might have better luck using [this library](http://code.google.com/p/cookies/) instead. Its description on Google Code is "Javascript Cookie Library with jQuery bindings and JSON support", and includes methods for everything you're trying to do!

Comment: Last update of jquery.cookie is 7 days ago, on 2013-09-11.  We are using that component that is very useful.

Comment: Could be that they picked up development again. When I made this comment the library hadn't been updated in over 2 years.

Comment: As of today, October 28 2015, the project has been totally updated and has a different name and implementation: https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie ... The old jquery.cookie script wasn't working for me at all, so I looked into it and switched over to the this new project and it is working well.